Can we have Multiple Interceptor for a single Http method in Nestjs?
Is it possible to have multiple interceptor for a single HTTP method.
for instance we a have a file upload method, where the express fileInterceptor handles.
And I have generalized response structure defined in a interceptor. so i wanted to use both of these interceptor for a single HTTP method.
Since I am new to Nestjs framework I am not familiar with the concept so wanted some insight on the same.

If you check out the Nest source code, you will be able to see that the decorator @UseInterceptors allows multiple interceptors:
export function UseInterceptors(
  ...interceptors: (NestInterceptor | Function)[]
): MethodDecorator & ClassDecorator {
//...

You can use it like this:
import { Controller, Post, UseInterceptors, UploadedFile, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { CustomResponseInterceptor } from './interceptors/custom-response.interceptor';

@Controller('upload')
export class UploadController {
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file'),
    CustomResponseInterceptor
  )
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Body() body: any) {
    // Your logic to handle the file and request body
    return { file, body };
  }
}

